# Loop through table variable and insert missing rows into new table variable

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a table variable which is populated with a number of rows. What I am trying to achieve, is to loop through each row of the table variable, see if the ID column exists in another standard table and add that row to a newly created table variable.

My code is as follows:

```
DECLARE
@Intervention_ID int

SET @Intervention_ID = 969

/*---Check if intervention has pre-requisites---*/
DECLARE @PreRequisites TABLE
(
    [Intervention_ID] int
)
INSERT INTO @PreRequisites
(
    [Intervention_ID]
)
SELECT IP.[Requisite_ID]
FROM DI_Intervention_Prerequisites IP
WHERE
    IP.[Intervention_ID] = @Intervention_ID
AND IP.[Prerequisite] = 1

/*---Check if pre-requisites have been completed---*/
DECLARE @Result TABLE
(
    [Type_ID] int
  , [Type_Name] nvarchar(max)
  , [Intervention_ID] int
  , [Intervention_Name] nvarchar(max)
)
WHILE NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT TOP 1 1
    FROM DI_Employee_Intervention EI
    WHERE
        EI.[Intervention_ID] = (SELECT [Intervention_ID] FROM @PreRequisites)
)
    INSERT INTO @Result
    (
        [Type_ID]
      , [Type_Name]
      , [Intervention_ID]
      , [Intervention_Name]
    )
```

As you can see, I am stuck at the `WHILE NOT EXISTS` part of the code. What needs to happen is for each row within `@PreRequisites` that does not exist in `DI_Employee_Intervention`, that specific `@PreRequisites` row need to be inserted into `@Result`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you just use a **set-based** approach instead of the RBAR (row-by-agonizing-row) procedural approach you have now??

Something like:

```
INSERT INTO @Result([Type_ID], [Type_Name], [Intervention_ID], [Intervention_Name])
  SELECT 
      ... (some columns to match the columns of @Result)......
  FROM 
     dbo.DI_Intervention_Prerequisites IP
  WHERE
     IP.[Intervention_ID] = @Intervention_ID
     AND IP.[Prerequisite] = 1
     AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * 
                     FROM DI_Employee_Intervention EI
                     WHERE EI.[Intervention_ID] = IP.[Intervention_ID] )
```

or something like that (I didn't quite understand all your intermediate steps and why you take them....)

Comment: Hi Marc, at the time my RBAR approach seemed to be fine...up until the WHERE clause. But I tried your solution and the result was correct. Thanks